# Finding the number of "good functions"

Tags: combinatorics, functions, contest-math

Consider $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ we call the function $f: B\to A$ "good function" if we have: for every element of $A$ like $x$ be at least one element of $B$ like $y$ so that $f(y)=x$ and $f(1)\le f(2)\le \ldots f(13)$. what is the number of good functions?

$$1)924\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad 2)1296\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)3888\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)7560\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)8440$$

To solve this problem I translated it as this problem:

Considered the digits of $f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(13)$ make a $13$ digits number so that this number contain all the digits $1,2,\ldots,7$ and its first digit is $1$ and last digit is $7$ also the digits are increasing. how many thirteen digits numbers have this condition?

So we know the first and last digits therefore eleven digits left. I am not sure how I should solve this combinatoric problem, but I think I should consider the number $1234567$ and add $6$ more digits between it so that the digits be increasing. I don't know how to count the number of the cases.

Comment: How do you ensure that the first and last digits are $1$ and $7$, respectively?

Comment: @VIVID because we should have all the $f(1),f(2),\ldots f(13)$ and also should have all the numbers from $1$ to $7$ as the output, because the digits are increasing first one should be $1$ and last digit should be $7$.

Comment: Why cannot you have $f(1) = f(2) = \dots f(13) = 7$?

Comment: @VIVID for every element of $A$ there is at least one element of $B$ (it is an assumption of the problem). therefore we should have all the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots 7$

Comment: I missed the surjectivity, sorry.

Comment: No problem. ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way to do this. When you pick a good function, you're partitioning the numbers from $1$ to $13$ into $7$ nonempty blocks. You can think of these blocks as being separated by walls, so for example $1|2\;3\;4|5|6\;7|8\;9\;10|11|12\;13$ represents a good function, where the numbers in the first block map to $1$, the numbers in the second block map to $2$, etc.

In other words, you need to choose the number of ways you can place the $6$ walls that divide the elements of $B$ into $7$ blocks. The walls need to go between elements of $B$ (if a wall goes to the left of $1$, or to the right of $13$, then the leftmost or rightmost block will be empty), and no two walls can go between the same elements of $B$, otherwise the block enclosed by those walls will be empty. Hence, you must choose $6$ places to put the walls among the $12$ places possible, so the answer is ${12\choose 6}=924$.

Comment: Very good answer. thank you very much!